# Filebeat does not send logs to elasticsearch from /var/log/containers/*.log

Tags: kubernetes, logging, filebeat, elk

I am trying to deploy the monitoring stack on kubernetes using ELK + filebeat , but filebeat doesnot send logs to the elasticsearch or logstash when pass the path as /var/log/containers/*.log in filebeat config ,but metricbeat is working fine , i can see all the workers metric logs in kibana .

elasticsearch.yaml

```
# RBAC authn and authz
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - "services"
  - "namespaces"
  - "endpoints"
  verbs:
  - "get"
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  apiGroup: ""
---
# Elasticsearch deployment itself
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    version: v6.2.4
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-logging
  replicas: 2
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
      version: v6.2.4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
        version: v6.2.4
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: elasticsearch-logging
      containers:
      - image: k8s.gcr.io/elasticsearch:v6.2.4
        name: elasticsearch-logging
        resources:
          # need more cpu upon initialization, therefore burstable class
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: db
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: elasticsearch-logging
          mountPath: /data
        env:
        - name: "NAMESPACE"
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      volumes:
      - name: elasticsearch-logging
        emptyDir: {}
      # Elasticsearch requires vm.max_map_count to be at least 262144.
      # If your OS already sets up this number to a higher value, feel free
      # to remove this init container.
      initContainers:
      - image: alpine:3.6
        command: ["/sbin/sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        name: elasticsearch-logging-init
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/name: "Elasticsearch"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: db
    nodePort: 31335
  selector:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
```

filebeat.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      enabled: true
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
    filebeat.config:
      prospectors:
        # Mounted `filebeat-prospectors` configmap:
        path: ${path.config}/prospectors.d/*.yml
        # Reload prospectors configs as they change:
        reload.enabled: false
      modules:
        path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
        # Reload module configs as they change:
        reload.enabled: false
    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:

 

    cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

 

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-prospectors
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
data:
  kubernetes.yml: |-
    - type: container
      enabled: true
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      containers.ids:
      - "*"
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  selector: # Add this selector field
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.3.0
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch-logging
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: changeme
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: prospectors
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/prospectors.d
          readOnly: true
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/log/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
          readOnly: true
        - name: varlogpods
          mountPath: /var/log/pods
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/containers
      - name: prospectors
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-prospectors
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlogpods
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/pods
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
```

logstash.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-configmap
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    # all input will come from filebeat, no local logs
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }
    filter {
      if [message] =~ /^\{.*\}$/ {
        json {
          source => "message"
        }
      }
      if [ClientHost] {
        geoip {
          source => "ClientHost"
        }
      }
    }
    output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "elasticsearch-logging:9200" ]
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash-deployment
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: # Add this selector field
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.3.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.yml
              path: logstash.yml
      - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.conf
              path: logstash.conf
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5044
    targetPort: 5044
  type: ClusterIP
```

metricbeat.yaml (this one is sending metrics to the kibana i can see it on index ) :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: metricbeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
data:
  metricbeat.yml: |-
    metricbeat.config.modules:
      # Mounted `metricbeat-daemonset-modules` configmap:
      path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
      # Reload module configs as they change:
      reload.enabled: false

    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:

    cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: metricbeat-daemonset-modules
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
data:
  system.yml: |-
    - module: system
      period: 10s
      metricsets:
        - cpu
        - load
        - memory
        - network
        - process
        - process_summary
        #- core
        #- diskio
        #- socket
      processes: ['.*']
      process.include_top_n:
        by_cpu: 5      # include top 5 processes by CPU
        by_memory: 5   # include top 5 processes by memory

    - module: system
      period: 1m
      metricsets:
        - filesystem
        - fsstat
      processors:
      - drop_event.when.regexp:
          system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib)($|/)'
  kubernetes.yml: |-
    - module: kubernetes
      metricsets:
        - node
        - system
        - pod
        - container
        - volume
      period: 10s
      hosts: ["localhost:10255"]
---
# Deploy a Metricbeat instance per node for node metrics retrieval
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metricbeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: metricbeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: metricbeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: metricbeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:6.3.0
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/metricbeat.yml",
          "-e",
          "-system.hostfs=/hostfs",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch-logging
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: changeme
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/metricbeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: metricbeat.yml
        - name: modules
          mountPath: /usr/share/metricbeat/modules.d
          readOnly: true
        - name: dockersock
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
        - name: proc
          mountPath: /hostfs/proc
          readOnly: true
        - name: cgroup
          mountPath: /hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: proc
        hostPath:
          path: /proc
      - name: cgroup
        hostPath:
          path: /sys/fs/cgroup
      - name: dockersock
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: metricbeat-config
      - name: modules
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: metricbeat-daemonset-modules
      # We set an `emptyDir` here to ensure the manifest will deploy correctly.
      # It's recommended to change this to a `hostPath` folder, to ensure internal data
      # files survive pod changes (ie: version upgrade)
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: metricbeat-deployment-modules
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
data:
  # This module requires `kube-state-metrics` up and running under `kube-system` namespace
  kubernetes.yml: |-
    - module: kubernetes
      metricsets:
        - state_node
        - state_deployment
        - state_replicaset
        - state_pod
        - state_container
        # Uncomment this to get k8s events:
        #- event
      period: 10s
      hosts: ["kube-state-metrics:8080"]
---
# Deploy singleton instance in the whole cluster for some unique data sources, like kube-state-metrics
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metricbeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: metricbeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: metricbeat
      containers:
      - name: metricbeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:6.3.0
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/metricbeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch-logging
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: changeme
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/metricbeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: metricbeat.yml
        - name: modules
          mountPath: /usr/share/metricbeat/modules.d
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: metricbeat-config
      - name: modules
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: metricbeat-deployment-modules
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metricbeat
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: metricbeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - events
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
```

I just could not find anything which can fix it , especially in filebeat.yaml which doesnt send any logs to kibana please help .